# Open excel file and export data

Tags: excel

I have three worksheets in an Excel file in spreadsheets1 and 2 have some expressions to calculate.
What better way to handle this excel file and export some data into the spreadsheet 3, whereas the sheets 1 and 2 will use the spreadsheet as a data source 3.

Comment: so you want to export some data into an excel sheet? Did I get that right?

Comment: Please don't add things like " - c# - asp.net" to the ends of your titles. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: I see you used the [tag:asp.net] tag. Do not use Office Automation from an ASP.NET project. It doesn't work.

Comment: Retagged to remove unrelated C# and asp.net tags. Your question has only to with Excel alone.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to move data from one spreadsheet to another you could write VB or record a macro.

Comment: I tagged C# and Asp.Net because my software will generate this data and save in a excel file with a template and I dont know how to start this..